# How would I batch edit video file metadata for an mp4?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, metadata, mp4

I have a number of mp4 files that need to contain the same metadata eg. artist & album.

How can I batch edit the metadata rather than doing them one by one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before proceeding, please make a backup copy of the videos you wish to process. The command below replaces the existing files.

```
find /home/user/videos-to-process/ -type f -iname '*.mp4' -exec ffmpeg -i "{}" -codec copy -metadata artist="John Smith" -metadata album="Foo Bar" "{}.new.mp4" \; -exec mv "{}.new.mp4" "{}" \;
```

Here's the same command, formatted for clarity:

```
find /home/user/videos-to-process/ -type f -iname '*.mp4' \
  -exec ffmpeg \
    -i "{}" \
    -codec copy \
    -metadata artist="John Smith" \
    -metadata album="Foo Bar" \
    "{}.new.mp4" \; \
  -exec mv \
    "{}.new.mp4" "{}" \;
```

What does this do?

1. Recursively finds all .mp4 files (case-insensitive extension comparison) in /home/user/videos-to-process.
2. Creates a new video file, copying the existing streams, with the desired metadata.
3. Replaces the original video file with the new video file.

Step 2 **copies** the existing streams; we are not reencoding (this is a good thing). You are simply changing the metadata. I ran this over a directory with six files, each about 1GB. Total processing time was about 30 seconds.

Comment: Instead of `ffmpeg`, you can use [`exiftool`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool) to modify metadata in-place.

Comment: @ridgy The [exiftool documentation](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/QuickTime.html) shows that most of the fields are not writable.  The only writable fields are PreviewDate, MediaCreateDate, MediaModifyDate, TrackCreateDate, TrackModifyDate, CreateDate, and ModifyDate. Were you able to use exiftool to add or modify Album or Artist?

Comment: I did not try, and it seems from the documentation that you are right. As I usually create audio data from raw data with `audacity`, I define the metadata there, and only use `exiftool` to sort the data. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: @ridgy No problem! I've been neck deep in exiftool over the past couple of weeks trying to clean up a massive photo archive. It's a great tool. I wish I could use it with MP4's.

Comment: @TooManyPets this seems to be working a treat thanks. I've tried searching google for the metadata fields used in mp4's but haven't found anything. Do you happen to know of a site where this is documented?

Comment: My video files have multiple audio streams, but after using this command, only one stream was left. I managed to fix this by adding the following: `-c:a copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2` It would be nice to simplify this even further, but I could not figure out how. I got this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45881847/314618

Answer (score 4):

You can use the utility `AtomicParsley` for this purpose. Install this from a Terminal window as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install atomicparsley
```

If you have your mp4 files in *a single directory* you can then simply open a Terminal window in that location and run the following:

```
for i in *.mp4
do
AtomicParsley "$i" --album "Foo" --artist "Bar" --overWrite
done
```

(This includes the undocumented but fully functional `--overWrite` tag.)

Obviously you should change the values `Foo` and `Bar` to represent *the actual values* you need to use in your files...

Comment: is it possible to add metadata into file, without creating duplicate. `--overWrite` still copies whole file